# SSIS: Mapping foreach variables containing null values to integers

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm using SSIS and BIDS to load data from `CSV` file to database. My datasource have a column with `integer nullable` values. First I load those values in a `recordset` destination and later I iterate over them in a `Foreach`. I map the int values to an `Object` variable, as integers can not be null. Inside foreach I have a simple Execute Sql, wich insert values to database. But it's no working, when null values comes, it throws an error:

```
Unsupported data type on parameter binding 0.". Possible failure reasons: 
Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters
not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Which is the right way to work with integer values in foreach container when datasource contains `nulls`?

Comment: How are you mapping `Integer` to `Object` variable ?

Comment: Yes, and it fails with the message posted before. I need to keep the null values, any ideas?

Comment: I've been playing with the Flat File Connection Manager. If I set the column to String data Type, it fails. If I set it to Int data type, it sets the value to 0 when nulls. I need to keep the null values in the flow.

Comment: Is there a business reason for taking this approach? The whole - map csv to recordset destination and then row by row perform inserts?

Comment: Yes, I need to mix the data from CSV file with data from other data sources. I omitted that step for simplicity. So far I found that it's only possible using an Script Task with custom code, I could not figure out how to map a null parameter from variable to Execute Sql Task..